# flutter test not finding widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this code that test if the button is on the screen:

```
void main() {
  testWidgets('Search for button', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(
      home: HomeView(),
    ));
    final button = find.byType(BotaoRedirecionamentoInterno);
    expect(button, findsWidgets);
  });
}
```

Is working as I expected, but when I try this code that search for another type of button in the same view it doenst work:

```
void main() {
  testWidgets('Search for button', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(
      home: HomeView(),
    ));
    final button = find.byType(BotaoRedirecionamentoExterno);
    expect(button, findsWidgets);
  });
}
```

I don't understand why because they are exactly one line below in the HomeView:

```
      Expanded(
        child: GridView.count(
          childAspectRatio: 6,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: screenWidth * .05, right: screenWidth * .05),
          mainAxisSpacing: screenHeight * 0.02,
          crossAxisCount: 1,
          children: const [
            BotaoRedirecionamentoInterno(texto: "aaa", rota: '/bbbb'),
            BotaoRedirecionamentoExterno(texto: 'aaa', url: "bbb"),
            BotaoRedirecionamentoExterno(texto: "aaa", url: "bbb"),
            BotaoRedirecionamentoExterno(texto: "aaa", url: "bbb"),
            BotaoRedirecionamentoExterno(texto: "aaa", url: 'bbb'),
            BotaoRedirecionamentoExterno(texto: "aaa", url: "bbb"),
          ],
        ),
      )
```

this is the error message :

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following TestFailure object was thrown running a test:
  Expected: at least one matching node in the widget tree
  Actual: _WidgetTypeFinder:<zero widgets with type "BotaoRedirecionamentoExterno" (ignoring
offstage widgets)>
```

I discovered that if I change the position inside the GridView to this:

```
 Expanded(
            child: GridView.count(
              childAspectRatio: 6,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: screenWidth * .05, right: screenWidth * .05),
              mainAxisSpacing: screenHeight * 0.02,
              crossAxisCount: 1,
              children: const [
                BotaoRedirecionamentoExterno(texto: 'aaa', url: "bbb"),
                BotaoRedirecionamentoInterno(texto: "aaa", rota: '/bbbb'),

                BotaoRedirecionamentoExterno(texto: "aaa", url: "bbb"),
                BotaoRedirecionamentoExterno(texto: "aaa", url: "bbb"),
                BotaoRedirecionamentoExterno(texto: "aaa", url: 'bbb'),
                BotaoRedirecionamentoExterno(texto: "aaa", url: "bbb"),
              ],
            ),
          )
```

The test finds the BotaoRedirecionamentoInterno but wont find BotaoRedirecionamentoExterno, so my guess is that is only finding the first widget inside the GridView.

Anyone could help me figure out what is happening ?

Comment: Try and find the `Expanded` or the `Gridview` first, if they can't be found you need to show us some more code to be able to help.

Comment: I can find the Expanded and the GridView. Other than that
 the button BotaoRedirecionamentoInterno is inside the Expanded too and only appears here.

Comment: But if you try `expect(find.byType(Expanded), findsWidgets)` does that find the expanded widget? If that fails the problem is higher up in your tree

Comment: It finds the expanded with no problem.

Comment: Maybe try `find.byElementType` instead of `find.byType`

Comment: I edited the question, because I noted that if I switch position inside the gridview, it changes the behavior.

Comment: In your last sentence did you mean , the test finds BotaoRedirecionamentoExterno but not BotaoRedirecionamentoInterno ? Because you say it only finds first widget in GridView and BotaoRedirecionamentoExterno is the first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dragUntilVisible which scrolls the GridView in right direction, look below one it will scroll till the `BotaoRedirecionamentoExterno` widget, you can replace it with any `Key` or `Text`..

```
await tester.dragUntilVisible(
    find.byType(BotaoRedirecionamentoExterno), // what you want to find
    find.byType(GridView), // widget you want to scroll
    const Offset(-250, -0), // delta to move
);
```

Answer (score 3):

The test may actually work as intended: your second child widget in the `Exanded` my not be visible on screen, and can therefore not be found. The `find` methods will only return Widgets that have been created, and the `Gridview` will not create all widgets if they are not visible.  The fact that it does show up if you swap the order suggests that the first `Interno` widget is large.